# How to add a hyperlink in XLS cell using JAVA

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink, xls

I need to add a hyperlink in XLS cell which should be linked to the file in my local drive using Java. Here is my code.

I need to link the corresponding file from the local folder to the corresponding cell in the XLs.

I'd tried to add hyperlink, but i can able add only URL in the not the file from the local disk. Please help me

```
public boolean to_write_xls( int max, List <String> temp_1,List <String> temp_2,List <String> temp_3,List <String> temp_4,List <String> temp_5 ) {

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Analyzed Result");
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.ORANGE.index);
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

    rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Passed TC's     ");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("CRC:Failure     ");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("unexpected RRC PDU");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("PCallback Error ");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Piggybacked NAS PDU");

/*    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
       // sheet.setColumnWidth(i,4000);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)i);


    }*/
    Iterator<Cell> ct = rowhead.iterator();
    int i=0;
    while(ct.hasNext()){
        Cell cell = (Cell) ct.next();
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)i);
        i ++;
    }
    CellStyle style_r = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style_r.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style_r.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style_r.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style_r.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

    i=0;
    while (i < max ) {

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i+2);

        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(temp_1.get(i));
        row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(temp_2.get(i));
        row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(temp_3.get(i));
        row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(temp_4.get(i));
        row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(temp_5.get(i));

        Iterator<Cell> rw = row.iterator();
         while(rw.hasNext()){
            Cell cell = (Cell) rw.next();
            cell.setCellStyle(style_r);
         }
        i++;
        }      




    try {

         FileOutputStream Fout =
     new FileOutputStream(new File(fin+"\\Result.xls"));
     workbook.write(Fout);
     Fout.close();
     //System.out.println("Excel written successfully..with the file name directory-----> D:\\_Analyzed_Result\\Result.xls");
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+fin+"\\Result.xls"); 
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

     return false;
 }


return true;
```

}

Comment: You really need to provide more information. What have you tried? What framework do you use to generate xls files? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above code is not working. so I find the some other code which is working fine, which is used to add a hyperlink in the cell.

```
CellStyle hlink_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font hlink_font = workbook.createFont();
hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
hlink_font.setColor(Font.COLOR_RED);
hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
Cell cell = null;     
cell=row.createCell((short) 1);
cell.setCellValue("Go to Result");
path_f="D://Result.xls";
link.setAddress(path_f);        
cell.setHyperlink(link);    
cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
```

It works 100% fine!!

Comment: In Apache POI 4.1.1, hyperlink can be created as follows: `Hyperlink link = workbook.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);` and more colors can be set using `hlink_font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLUE.getIndex());`

Answer (score 1):

Developers can add hyperlinks to external Excel files by calling the Add method of Hyperlinks collection. The Add method takes the following parameters:

Cell Name , represents the cell name where the hyperlink will be added

Number of Rows , represents the number of rows in this hyperlink range

Number of Columns , represents the number of columns of this hyperlink range

URL , represents the address of the external Excel file that will be used as a hyperlink

[Java]

//Instantiating a Workbook object

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
```

//Obtaining the reference of the first worksheet.

```
WorksheetCollection worksheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
Worksheet sheet = worksheets.get(0);
```

//Setting a value to the "A1" cell

```
Cells cells = sheet.getCells();
Cell cell = cells.get("A1");
cell.setValue("Visit Aspose");
```

//Setting the font color of the cell to Blue

```
Style style = cell.getStyle();
style.getFont().setColor(Color.getBlue());
```

//Setting the font of the cell to Single Underline

```
style.getFont().setUnderline(FontUnderlineType.SINGLE);
cell.setStyle(style);

HyperlinkCollection hyperlinks = sheet.getHyperlinks();
```

//Adding a link to the external file

```
hyperlinks.add("A5", 1, 1, "C:\\book1.xls");
```

//Saving the Excel file

```
workbook.save("c:\\book2.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can create hyperlink in excel sheet using this java code

```
 File veri1 = new File("your_ file_path");
                    FileInputStream inputStream_ED1 = new FileInputStream(veri1);
                    HSSFWorkbook workbook_ED1 = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream_ED1);
                    HSSFSheet sheet_ED1 = workbook_ED1.getSheet("Result");
                    CreationHelper createHelper = workbook_ED1.getCreationHelper();
                    HSSFCellStyle hlinkstyle = workbook_ED1.createCellStyle();
                    HSSFFont hlinkfont = workbook_ED1.createFont();
                    hlinkfont.setUnderline(HSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
                    hlinkfont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
                    hlinkstyle.setFont(hlinkfont);
                    Iterator<Row> riterator_ED1 = sheet_ED1.iterator();
                    Row row_ED1 = sheet_ED1.createRow(sheet_ED1.getLastRowNum()+1);
                    if(sheet_ED1.getLastRowNum()==0){

                    }


                 Cell DeviceName = row_ED1.createCell(0);
                 DeviceName.setCellValue(DeviceID.toString());   

                 Cell Module = row_ED1.createCell(1);
                 Module.setCellValue(module.toString());

                 Cell SubModule1 = row_ED1.createCell(2);
                 SubModule1.setCellValue(SubModule.toString());


                 Cell ScenarioID1 = row_ED1.createCell(3);
                 ScenarioID1.setCellValue(ScenarioID.toString());

                 Cell TestcaseID = row_ED1.createCell(4);
                 TestcaseID.setCellValue(TestCaseID.toString());

                 Cell TCDescription = row_ED1.createCell(5);
                 TCDescription.setCellValue(testcasedis.toString());

                 Cell ExpectedResult1 = row_ED1.createCell(6);
                 ExpectedResult1.setCellValue(ExpectedResult.toString());

                 Cell ActualResult1 = row_ED1.createCell(7);
                 ActualResult1.setCellValue(ActualResult.toString());

                 Cell Status1 = row_ED1.createCell(8);
                 Status1.setCellValue(Status.toString());

                 Cell time = row_ED1.createCell(9);
                 time.setCellValue(Time.toString());

                 Cell ExecutionDate1 = row_ED1.createCell(10);
                 ExecutionDate1.setCellValue(ExecutionDate.toString());

                 HSSFHyperlink link = (HSSFHyperlink)createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
                 Cell ss = row_ED1.createCell((short) 11);
                 ss.setCellValue(sspath.toString());
                 link = (HSSFHyperlink)createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
                 link.setAddress(sspath.toString());
                 ss.setHyperlink(link);
                 ss.setCellStyle(hlinkstyle);

                 FileOutputStream 


    os_ED1 = new FileOutputStream(veri1);
                 workbook_ED1.write(os_ED1);

                 os_ED1.close();
                 workbook_ED1.close();
                 inputStream_ED1.close();
```

Comment: This is an old and aleady answered question, could you please also explain the code you posted, or add some fundamentally comments into the code, so this answer can provide some more value than that?